# Rails Generate Unique Order No which has not been used before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate an Order No and want to make sure that is not in use just for security.

1. I want to generate a Order Number
2. Check if the Order Number is not used before then use it
3. If its used before repeat from 1 again.

**Unique Generator**

```
def secure_token
    DateTime.now.strftime("%Y/%m/").to_s + SecureRandom.hex(16/4).upcase
  end
```

Now i want to write the logic to check if that is not used.

```
while Order.where.not(:order_no => secure_token) do
 @order_no = secure_token
end
```

When i try to run the above it keeps running and never exits. There are no records in the DB as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better & correct way:

```
order_no = nil

loop do
  order_no = secure_token
  break unless Order.exists?(:order_no => order_no)
end

Order.new(:order_no => order_no, ....)
```

Comment: it says not a local variable. which is the best way to initiate a variable? order_no = ''

Comment: `order_no = nil` before `loop`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `Order.where` always returns relation, which is truthy, even if it's empty. Use `first`:

```
while Order.where.not(order_no: secure_token).first do
```

Comment: I have just finished typing it and you already posted an asnwer, how cound you be so quick!? :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I type faster than 400 characters per minute. :)

Comment: @MarekLipka this must be a reason ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can generate whatever number and append the Order database ID to its first/middle/end whatever you want that would guarantee uniqueness as your Order database ID can't be repeated.